# Issues with JSON and Heroku

Tags: python, json, database, heroku, discord

I've created a simple discord bot with python that takes in quotes from a json file and prints them out when necessary. It works fine locally but when I deploy it on heroku, it doesn't seem to work. It's come to my attention that heroku doesn't function with json files and I need to create a database for the quotes. Why does this happen? Are there any simple alternative solutions?

Comment: Check in Heroku page if worker runs. You might need to add one manualy.
Check this guide https://shiffman.net/a2z/bot-heroku/

Comment: I'm sure the bot is deployed because it performs all of the other programmed functions except the ones involved in fetching data